# How to make query run in 'order' when executing without using 'GO' (for Stored Procedure)?

Tags: t-sql

I have a query that does a large bulk insert from a CSV. The CSV is formatted in a very specific way so this query I use has lots of lines involving the creation of temp tables, altering and updating columns in them, and then dropping them, etc, etc. It requires lots of 'steps' in the query but I'm happy with it as it's very efficient/fast.

Eg portion:

```
--5
UPDATE #Map_M
SET Site = REPLACE(Site, ' ', '')
GO

--6
ALTER TABLE #Map_M
ADD P_V NUMERIC(12,3)
GO

--7
UPDATE #Map_M
SET P_V = TRY_CAST(Mock_P_V AS NUMERIC(12,3))
GO

-8
ALTER TABLE #Map_M
DROP COLUMN Mock_P_V
GO
```

To get this to work with an SP, though, I had to I swap 'GO' for ';' but when I do that the query fails because it doesn't seem like it's order of execution is honoring the order of the way the query is written. For example, I'm getting an error *'Invalid column name 'P_V''*. I'm assuming it's because the **UPDATE #Map_M SET P_V = TRY_CAST(Mock_P_V AS NUMERIC(12,3));** is executing before **ALTER TABLE #Map_M ADD P_V NUMERIC(12,3);** when I swap GO for ;.

Wondering how to resolve this?

Comment: [`GO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15) is a batch separator used by SSMS and other utilities to control the execution of statements. If you want to achieve the same functionality in a stored procedure you'll need to use _dynamic SQL_ and [execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) batches separately.

Comment: you might want to check BEGIN / COMMIT TRAN  commands

Comment: Do you really execute this code in a procedure? My experience is, that there is a syntax check if the temporary table already exists. Within a procedure the temporary table goes out of scope at the end of the execution. Within a script it's in scope until the connection is closed. Adding DROP TABLE #Map_M at the end of the script should help.